# How can I capture the user's name before they are able to work on a gSheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog, radio-button

I have a 3 virtual assistants that do data entry into a google sheet.  There are four of us that have edit permission to work on the sheet. Typically the sheet will be populated with a business name, address, phone, and a link to their website.  The data comes from an gMaps API.

The virtual assistants use a hyperlink on the Sheet to open a website so they can gather more info about the business.  On the sheet there are columns for the worker's name and a time stamp when the record was last updated.  I pay the workers based on the time they start working and when 10 minutes after their last entry.  I have all this working but the worker must enter her name and and a time stamp for each record.

I want to automate the process of entering their user name.  Currently I use a drop down menu in a cell for each record.  The worker enters their name and a time stamp for each record and there are thousands of records being updated.

My desired result is that the worker be prompted to select their name from a radio button that is in a Dialog Box.  One of the buttons is selected by default. The worker picks their name and hits a submit button.   The name selected is captured to a global variable for use by a cell formula whenever the worker edits a row of data.  The worker should not be able to work on the sheet until they have selected a radio button and submitted their selection.  There should be no way to work on the sheet until a name has been selected and submitted.

I started this project not understanding that onOpen can not do what I wanted it to do... As a work around I created a custom menu with one choice...  Open the Dialog box... I also did not understand that I would need an HTML file in my project. Since I am a newbie I did not want to create any more than the one HTML file.  And I dont know anything about CSS etc.

I watched a lot of videos and visited many sites that offer help with gSheets.  I used an AI tool to help me sort out some things and to answer a lot of my questions related to the error messages my code throws.

The problem I am having is related to preventing the worker from canceling my script and getting access to the sheet without first selecting their name and click on the submit button.  I don't want the dialog box to have the little X in the upper right corner or to have a cancel button or some keyboard way to exit.

I was never able to get my code to work from onOpen function.  But I did get it to work from a custom menu.  Which I can live with, as long as the user can not edit the sheet until they submit their name.

My code throws an error and does not open the dialog box.   In an earlier attempt I got the dialog box to show.. with the radio buttons... but I made changes and broke the script and can't figure this out.

Once I get this part working, I think I can manage most of my other things I want to do.

```
// Code.gs - created by djweller44@gmail.com on April 5, 2023 at 02:29 GMT-0

/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

var userName;

function onOpen() {
  Logger.log("Code.gs: onOpen() function called.");

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu');
  menu.addItem('Get User Name', 'showDialog');
  menu.addToUi();

  Logger.log("Code.gs: Custom menu created.");
}

function showDialog() {
  Logger.log("Code.gs: showDialog() function called.");

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  html.userName = userName;

  var dialog = html.evaluate()
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.showModalDialog(dialog, 'Please enter your name:');

  if (result == "cancel") {
    Logger.log("Code.gs: User canceled the dialog box.");
  } else {
    Logger.log("Code.gs: User name entered: " + result);
    handleFormSubmit({userName: result});
  }
}

function handleFormSubmit(form) {
  Logger.log("Code.gs: handleFormSubmit() function called.");

  var name = form.userName;

  if (name == "Dennis") {
    userName = "Dennis";
    Logger.log("Code.gs: User name stored: " + userName);
  } else if (name == "Helen") {
    userName = "Helen";
    Logger.log("Code.gs: User name stored: " + userName);
  } else {
    userName = "Other";
    Logger.log("Code.gs: User name stored: " + userName);
  }
}

Logger.log("Code.gs: code loaded"); 

======================================================================

<!-- index.html - created by djweller44@gmail.com on April 6, 2023 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Hello <?= userName ?>!</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the sheet. This is a demo of using a dialog box to prompt the user to input their name.</p>
      <form id="myForm">
        <label><input type="radio" name="userName" value="Dennis"> Dennis</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="userName" value="Helen"> Helen</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="userName" value="Other"> Other</label>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?!= include('Javascript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

=====================================================================

```
Execution log
7:34:26 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:34:26 PM  Info    Code.gs: code loaded
7:34:26 PM  Info    Code.gs: showDialog() function called.
7:34:26 PM  Error   
Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.
showDialog  @ Code.gs:24
```

Comment: You mentioned problems/limitations with `onOpen`. A `simple` trigger has certain limitations but you can also create an `installable onOpen` trigger which . Have you tried that? [onOpen doesn't execute](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/81131/196152) on WebApps has an example that includes `var email = (Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());` which is something along the lines that you are trying to do.

Comment: How are you executing `showDialog()` from the menu?